# time or timing in C#, and another question

Tags: c#

the question is:
how can i for example every two seconds without user intervention make a label flashes.
like every 2 seconds label.text="". and the next two seconds i do this label1.text="visible"
or changing another property like color or anything.

## i give up

could you help me with a basic code, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: When you mention time, do you mean elapsed time since you started the loop OR the actual system time? If you looking for elapsed time, you could take a look at the StopWatch class.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with a 2-second interval. But keep in mind, whenever you play with threads outside of the UI, you need to look in to [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx)

To accomplish what you're after, you *could* run it every 1 second, then check against [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to see if the clock matches your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I'll give it my best shot.

From what I understand, you want your code to do something every two seconds. The easiest way to do that is with a timer. The `System.Timers.Timer` class is useful for that, as well as `System.Threading.Timer`. Which you use is up to you, but the one in the Threading namespace is a little more primitive.

Timers operate on a ThreadPool, so if you will be manipulating a Windows Form, make sure what you do happens on the GUI thread either by using `Control.Invoke` for Windows Forms or `Dispatcher.Invoke` for WPF. Timers are also a little tricky because their Threading Apartment is typically MTA, so if you try to access the clipboard or something like that, you may get errors.

If you want to ensure your timer fires *exactly* at a certain time, rather than at a specific interval, you could make a timer with a period that starts another timer, or adjusts itself. I would argue that if you are doing something every 2 or 5 seconds do you *really* need it to happen at a very specific time? Timers, and Windows Time in general isn't specific enough and has small inaccuracies - it will drift over time by a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do with one thread is something like this :

- Sleep 2 seconds
- DoAction
- Sleep 2 seconds
- DoAnotherAction

In a loop.

With 2 threads, I would recommend something like this : [C# Running timed job on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519910/running-timed-job)

**Edit** : use [QuartzNet (tutorial)](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html).

A link [on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net).

Comment: how can i determine the time?

Comment: @user527825 : Use another Tick Thread, look at the article I set in my edit :)

Comment: Why would you use a thread to do this when it's so much easier to just use a timer?  This is a completely inappropriate use of threads.

Comment: @Jim Mischel : Simply because I didn't know about the Timer class, and while I reckon it's a lot simpler with it, if you don't know about it and you need to have exactly 2 seconds between each call, you'll end up using 2 Threads, 1 Tick Thread (the main Thread) and 1 or more Working Threads. The fact is that, even if I use the Timer, I would use Working Threads to do the job each 2 seconds in the OnTimed Event.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).  You can drop it on your form and set the interval, and create the `Tick` event handler.  The linked documentation has a simple example that you can easily modify to work with your label.

The beauty of using this timer is that it automatically synchronizes with the UI thread, so you don't have to worry about `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke`, etc.